# the slide animation of jquery doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

i would to slide a div from left to right side when clicked on a button. i use the following code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button type="button" onClick="f1()">click</button>
    <div id="p1" style="display:none">
        content
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function f1(){
        $('#p1').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 5000);
    }
</script>
```

but the transition doesn't occurs and the slide animation doesn't show. the "p1" div immediately shows after the button clicked. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect doesn't come with the basic jquery Package. You have to enque the jQuery UI library also.
[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

See this documentation for further slide effects [Slide effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/)